# JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am using a really easy JavaScript (AngularJS, but that is not relevant) like:

```
app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller("NavCtrl",function($scope,$http){
    var serviceBase = 'api/';
    $http.get(serviceBase + 'orders').then(function (results) {
        $scope.categories = results.data;
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++){
        var categories = $scope.categories[i];   
    }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-3" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
      <div class="sm-st clearfix">
      <!--<span class="sm-st-icon st-red"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i></span>-->
       <div class="sm-st-info">
       <i class="fa fa-square"></i>
       <span>Sander</span>
       <p>1 minutes</p>
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat= "p in categories">
                  {{p.orderID}}
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**API**

```
//PHPSLIM
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

//GET ALL ORDERS
$app->get('/orders', function(){
$extranames = "";
$extrasprice = 0;
    global $conn, $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;
    $sql = "SELECT `orderID`, `customerID`, `storeID`, `orderDate`, `orderDeliveryDate`, `orderStatus` FROM `order`";

    mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `orderID`, `customerID`, `orderDate`, `orderDeliveryDate`, `orderStatus` FROM `order`");
    $ordersall = array();

    while($line = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        $orders[] = $line;
    }

    $count = 0;
    $extrasprice = 0;

    foreach($orders as $key => $looporders){
        $extracounter = 1;

        $sql = "SELECT `orderdetailID`, `productID`, `orderdetailAantal`  FROM `orderdetail` WHERE `orderID` = '$looporders[orderID]'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $sql2 = "SELECT `productTitle`, `productPrijs`  FROM `products` WHERE `productID` = '$row[productID]'";
            $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
                if($result2->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
                        $productTitle = $row2["productTitle"];
                        $productPrijs = $row2["productPrijs"];

                    }
                } 
            $sql3 = "SELECT `customerName` FROM `customers` WHERE `customerID` = '$looporders[customerID]'";
            $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
                if($result3->num_rows > 0) {
                    while($row3 = $result3->fetch_assoc()){
                        $customerName = $row3["customerName"];
                    }
                }    
            $sql4 = "SELECT `extraID` FROM `orderdetailextra` WHERE `orderdetailID` = '$row[orderdetailID]'";
            $result4 = $conn->query($sql4);

            if ($result4->num_rows > 0) {
                while($row4 = $result4->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $sql5 = "SELECT `extraName`, `extraPrice` FROM `extra` WHERE `extraID` = '$row4[extraID]'";
                    $result5 = $conn->query($sql5);
                    if ($result5->num_rows > 0) {       
                     while($row5 = $result5->fetch_assoc()) {   

                        $extranames = $extranames . $row5["extraName"]. ', ';
                        $extrasprice += $row5["extraPrice"];    
                     }
                    }  
                 }
                }  

                $ordersall[$count] = array(  
                "orderID" => $looporders["orderID"],
                "customerID" => $looporders["customerID"],
                "customerName" => $customerName,
                "orderDate" => $looporders["orderDate"],
                "orderDeliveryDate" => $looporders["orderDeliveryDate"],
                "orderStatus" => $looporders["orderStatus"],
                "orderdetailID" => $row["orderdetailID"],
                "productTitle" => $productTitle,
                "productPrijs" => $productPrijs,
                "aantal" => $row["orderdetailAantal"],
                "extras" => substr($extranames, 0, -2),                
                "extrasPrice" => $extrasprice            
            );                

                $count++;
                $extranames ="";
                $extrasprice = 0;

            }
        }


    }

    echoResponse(200, $ordersall);

});

$app->run();

function echoResponse($status_code, $response) {
    global $app;
    $app->status($status_code);
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $app->contentType('application/json');
    echo json_encode($response,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
```

**JSON**

```
[{"orderID":4,"customerID":1,"customerName":"Sander","orderDate":"2015-04-20 09:49:06","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"done","orderdetailID":2,"productTitle":"Sexy Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},
{"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Jelle","orderDate":"2015-04-20 12:05:09","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":3,"productTitle":"The Coach","productPrijs":3,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},

    {"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Jelle","orderDate":"2015-04-20 12:05:09","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":4,"productTitle":"The Virgin","productPrijs":3.2,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},

    {"orderID":5,"customerID":2,"customerName":"Jelle","orderDate":"2015-04-20 12:05:09","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":5,"productTitle":"Sexy Teacher","productPrijs":4,"aantal":3,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},

    {"orderID":22,"customerID":11,"customerName":"Tom","orderDate":"2015-04-20 14:15:12","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":22,"productTitle":"The Virgin","productPrijs":3.2,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""},

    {"orderID":22,"customerID":11,"customerName":"Tom","orderDate":"2015-04-20 14:15:12","orderDeliveryDate":"2015-04-20","orderStatus":"prepare","orderdetailID":23,"productTitle":"The Virgin","productPrijs":3.2,"aantal":1,"extras":"","extrasprice":""}]
```

Now I am getting an error:

> JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1.

Is there something wrong with my JavaScript or PHP and how can this be fixed?
I don't think there is anything wrong with my code or data I am passing on...

Comment: cna you post the json response of your service?

Comment: I added a sample of my json response

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but where is the code that actually generates the JSON?

Comment: I am using php slim to generate apis, in the php part I generate this api which returns json data. Then later in javascript I call this api to get the data provided above?

Comment: check the server set correcly the content type as json

Comment: Only for trying, do a forcing the json content type response as `header("Content-Type: application/json");`

Comment: I set it in the echoResponse function but still the same error

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `JSON.parse` on an array of `JSON objects`, please use instead something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
    console.log(jsonData.orderID);
}
```

Also, I can't see any field `categories` in your `JSON` result.

Comment: indeed in the html it should be <li ng-repeat= "p in categories">, I edited. But where shouldn't I use json.parse but your recommendation?

Comment: On which line are you getting your error ? (sorry to answer with my own question)

Comment: Error: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 10563 of the JSON data
fromJson@http://localhost/localsites/serf/wea/web/libs/angular.js:1072:9

Comment: As you notice, you are the only one who can access to the file, please paste it there !

Comment: That's nothing more than a angular library needed to use angular in this project? It's 20k lines of code downloaded from the angular site you need it to get even started using angular in your own projects... It throws that error cause something else is wrong in my written code

Comment: Comment `for(var i = 0; i < $scope.categories.length; i++){
        var categories = $scope.categories[i];   
    }`, do you still get the error ?